# Find a equation based on a given zero.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I am given a zero of an equation, in this case $(5-\sqrt3)^{1/3}$. I need to find a polynomial in which this is a zero. ie for $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ the equation is $x^4-4x^2+2=0$. This is the only information I know. How would I go about finding this equation?

Comment: There *should* be more information otherwise I guess you will be not satisfied with the answers. E.g. take the polynomial $p(x)=0$, every number is a zero of $p$. If $p$ should not be the zero polynomial but $a$ should be a zero, then take the linear polynomial $p(x)=x-a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x=(5-\sqrt 3)^{1/3}$$
$$x^3=5-\sqrt 3$$
$$5-x^3=\sqrt 3$$
$$(5-x^3)^2=3$$
$$25-10x^3+x^6-3=0$$
$$x^6-10x^3+22=0$$
One polynomial with this root is
$$p(x)=x^6-10x^3+22$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $\require{cancel}\begin{cases}(5 + \bcancel{\sqrt{3}})+(5 - \bcancel{\sqrt{3}})=10 \\ (5 + \sqrt{3})\cdot(5 - \sqrt{3})=5^2-\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2 = 22\end{cases}\implies 5 \pm \sqrt{3}$ are the roots of $x^2-10 x +22\,$
- if $x$ is a root of $P(x)$ then $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is a root of $P(x^3)$

---

[ *EDIT* ]  To elaborate on the first bullet point, the hint is using the fact that the monic polynomial with roots $\,a,b\,$ is $\,x^2 - (a+b)x+ab\,$. This follows from [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas), or directly by expanding the product $(x-a)(x-b)\,$. Also, the second root was chosen to be $\,5+\sqrt{3}\,$ because a polynomial with integer coefficients which has $\,5-\sqrt{3}\,$ as a root must also have its [rational conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Radical_conjugate_roots) as a root.

Comment: You may want to explicitly mention Viete's formulas for your first bullet point: not everyone knows them or how to use them.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Fair point, thanks. Edited some more background into the answer.